# How to share file attachment to Teams chat via MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'd like to post a Teams chat message via MS graph API that includes attachments.
This works fine except that **the receiver cannot open the file (seems like no permission).**

I used code from this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-send-a-message-with-file-attachment-in-it

Currently I'm uploading the file via `POST /me/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content`

Then I post the message via `POST /chats/{chat-id}/messages` with a body like this

```
{
  body: {
    content: "here is the file <attachment id="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"></attachment>",
    contentType: "html"
  },
  attachments: [{
    id: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    contentType: "reference", 
    name: docker-compose.yml,
    contentUrl: https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxx_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/docker-compose.yml
  }]
}
```

Any advice what is wrong here?

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue is that the user is unable to open the attachment? Also please note that the file must already be in SharePoint.

Comment: Yes, the file is available in sharepoint since I can download it but the receiving user cannot.

Comment: As a workaround we created a shared link of the file and posted the link in the message instead of the file.